# Scikit-learn. Only positive Linear Regression with zero koeff

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to fit a linear regression model to find coefficients that must be strictly positive. Some of the coefficients turn to zero. How can this be avoided? I thought about normalizing values, but linear models are not sensitive to it.

Data:

```
y = [1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 2.12 2.12 2.12 2.61 2.61 2.61 3.09 3.09 3.09
3.26 3.26 3.26 3.26 3.26 4.07 4.07 4.07 4.07 4.07 2.93 2.93 2.93 2.93
2.93 2.28 2.28 2.28 2.28 2.28 3.26 3.26 3.26 3.26 2.28 2.28 2.28 2.28
2.61 2.61 2.61 2.61 2.61 4.07 4.07 4.07 4.07 4.07]

x = [[3.51714000e-05 1.41935534e+00 3.41061326e-02 1.85240055e-01]
[3.71250000e-05 1.45824179e+00 3.55173112e-02 1.90315125e-01]
[1.48500000e-04 2.91648357e+00 3.09101928e-02 3.60360000e-02]
[7.27650000e-05 2.04153850e+00 4.34470222e-02 1.45297152e-01]
[8.57736000e-05 2.21652751e+00 4.71031486e-02 1.44879134e-01]
[3.14226000e-05 1.34158244e+00 3.61634395e-02 2.33107875e-01]
[7.00194000e-05 2.00265205e+00 5.27645109e-02 2.22702480e-01]
[1.22073600e-04 2.64427844e+00 5.33707349e-02 1.30690560e-01]
[7.55634000e-05 2.08042495e+00 6.98347784e-02 3.61486125e-01]
[2.53704000e-05 1.20547988e+00 3.77841965e-02 3.15175661e-01]
[1.25690400e-04 2.68316488e+00 7.84190007e-02 2.74031257e-01]
[1.72142850e-04 3.14008064e+00 8.63303743e-02 2.42492250e-01]
[6.60000000e-05 1.94432238e+00 7.36110279e-02 4.59834375e-01]
[1.05600000e-05 7.77728952e-01 2.34108672e-02 2.90690400e-01]
[2.65038400e-04 3.72052961e+00 2.84183419e-02 1.70666496e-02]
[1.00000000e-04 2.28533760e+00 1.00327169e-01 5.63763200e-01]
[1.82790400e-04 3.08977644e+00 1.11120098e-01 3.78348006e-01]
[6.40000000e-05 1.82827008e+00 8.15775894e-02 5.82400000e-01]
[2.93094400e-04 3.91249797e+00 5.61842009e-02 6.03226624e-02]
[1.32710400e-04 2.63270892e+00 1.40966074e-01 8.38656000e-01]
[2.38393600e-04 3.52856125e+00 1.46548587e-01 5.04577965e-01]
[1.80633600e-04 3.07149373e+00 1.50991923e-01 7.06917120e-01]
[5.95984000e-05 1.76428063e+00 8.89323315e-02 7.43266160e-01]
[6.14656000e-05 1.79170468e+00 8.70567934e-02 6.90609920e-01]
[7.46496000e-05 1.97453169e+00 6.63811096e-02 3.30613920e-01]
[1.93766400e-04 3.18118994e+00 7.48953288e-02 1.62140160e-01]
[5.65504000e-05 1.71857388e+00 6.24513649e-02 3.86284954e-01]
[1.00000000e-04 2.28533760e+00 9.12065177e-02 4.65920000e-01]
[1.74240000e-04 3.01664563e+00 6.05152495e-02 1.17717600e-01]
[9.21600000e-05 2.19392410e+00 6.97037420e-02 2.95276800e-01]
[8.76096000e-05 2.13907599e+00 5.57498137e-02 1.98698573e-01]
[5.18400000e-05 1.64544307e+00 5.36321685e-02 3.10774464e-01]
[1.76358400e-04 3.03492833e+00 2.44264884e-02 1.89489664e-02]
[1.32710400e-04 2.63270892e+00 5.63864298e-02 1.34184960e-01]
[2.63737600e-04 3.71138826e+00 4.24705055e-02 3.83056128e-02]
[6.65856000e-05 1.86483548e+00 7.47930308e-02 4.70545421e-01]
[1.36422400e-04 2.66927432e+00 9.71413029e-02 3.87419760e-01]
[1.90440000e-04 3.15376589e+00 9.05629575e-02 2.41214064e-01]
[7.32736000e-05 1.95624899e+00 5.50777727e-02 2.31880813e-01]
[1.48840000e-04 2.78811187e+00 6.14519438e-02 1.42105600e-01]
[6.56100000e-05 1.85112346e+00 5.56849993e-02 2.64707352e-01]
[1.00000000e-04 2.28533760e+00 6.61247253e-02 2.44899200e-01]
[1.44000000e-04 2.74240512e+00 7.86804907e-02 2.40786000e-01]
[5.71536000e-05 1.72771523e+00 5.62056331e-02 3.09582000e-01]
[8.46400000e-05 2.10251059e+00 7.04231859e-02 3.28182400e-01]
[1.11513600e-04 2.41331651e+00 7.85607263e-02 3.09986477e-01]
[1.98246400e-04 3.21775534e+00 4.19046821e-02 4.96111616e-02]
[2.31040000e-04 3.47371315e+00 1.33530749e-01 4.32250000e-01]
[1.10670400e-04 2.40417516e+00 1.23015404e-01 7.65856000e-01]
[1.40185600e-04 2.70583972e+00 1.35129842e-01 7.29556173e-01]
[6.40000000e-05 1.82827008e+00 8.56564689e-02 6.42096000e-01]
[6.72400000e-05 1.87397683e+00 9.10049741e-02 6.89861900e-01]
[1.71500000e-04 2.44959624e+00 9.58437919e-02 3.00001520e-01]
[1.36281600e-04 2.18364008e+00 8.69252274e-02 3.10537500e-01]
[7.79744000e-05 1.65172775e+00 8.23463666e-02 4.87075680e-01]
[1.57304000e-05 7.41877718e-01 2.89189170e-02 2.97772020e-01]
[4.23864000e-05 1.21779927e+00 5.96616176e-02 4.70352137e-01]
[8.61056000e-05 1.73571391e+00 4.13962250e-02 1.11467866e-01]
[1.50617600e-04 2.29562162e+00 4.12265874e-02 6.32031400e-02]
[4.89566000e-05 1.30878428e+00 3.87210912e-02 1.71531360e-01]
[1.69400000e-05 7.69873104e-01 1.95073267e-02 1.25817692e-01]
[4.73984000e-05 1.28778774e+00 2.51953649e-02 7.50131200e-02]
[1.63296000e-05 7.55875411e-01 1.47289879e-02 7.44097536e-02]
[7.93016000e-05 1.66572544e+00 2.87250674e-02 5.82773464e-02]
[2.98424000e-05 1.02183157e+00 2.22604129e-02 9.30020000e-02]
[5.82624000e-05 1.42776467e+00 5.29433813e-02 2.69460173e-01]
[9.75744000e-05 1.84769545e+00 4.54662471e-02 1.18659341e-01]
[7.60046000e-05 1.63073121e+00 7.18055141e-02 3.79957760e-01]
[1.14514400e-04 2.00167007e+00 7.62891883e-02 2.84659375e-01]
[3.32024000e-05 1.07782235e+00 4.09952873e-02 2.83503220e-01]
[3.58400000e-05 1.11981542e+00 4.08605199e-02 2.60915200e-01]
[1.40000000e-05 6.99884640e-01 2.27131012e-02 2.06388000e-01]
[4.14176000e-05 1.20380158e+00 2.04941117e-02 5.67979776e-02]
[6.29216000e-05 1.48375544e+00 1.55800094e-02 2.16070400e-02]
[3.23456000e-05 1.06382465e+00 1.46609125e-02 3.72191456e-02]
[2.36600000e-05 9.09850032e-01 1.49626648e-02 5.29984000e-02]]
```

I think this is due to different weights in x

Code:

```
reg = LinearRegression(positive = True, fit_intercept = False).fit(x, y)
popt = reg.coef_
```

Result:

```
[0.         0.71429347 0.         3.62406594]
```

Comment: You could drop those features. Or add 1e-12 to those coefficients. Or maybe try L2 regularization (Ridge). Or challenge the requirement. But either way you will probably get further asking on  Cross Validated, since your question is not about programming at all.